# .NET 4.5 breaking an app

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, devexpress, .net-4.5

I have a .NET app which works well with .NET 4.0 - I don't have its source though the app exposes its app.config

But.

I have installed the Visual Studio 2012 with .NET 4.5. Suddenly, the .NET 4.0 application is throwing exceptions at some places - I analyzed with Reflector that the exceptions are thrown in InitializeComponent() in the WPF part of the application.

```
   Uri resourceLocator = new Uri("/Some.Assembly;someuri/someuri/somefile.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

And the exception is:

```
The invocation of the constructor on type 'DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.GridControl' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.

at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
```

Unfortunately I'm unable to tell if there's any inner exception.

If I uninstall .NET 4.5 and install .NET 4.0, the exceptions are not thrown but I can't work with VS 2012.

I've tried to add these lines into the app.config but without success.

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" >
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
    <requiredRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
</startup>
```

How does one force an app to use 4.0 and 4.0 only? Is it even possible? Is the .NET 4.5 somehow mingling with the 4.0 assemblies?

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe that 4.5 replaces 4.0, so I don't think you can have 4.5 installed but use the 4.0 runtime for that app.

Comment: @Gabe - you can still **target** the 4.0 framework though.

Comment: @slugster: You can target any framework, but targeting the 4.0 framework doesn't help when the 4.5 framework is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this article. http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Mar/13/NET-45-is-an-inplace-replacement-for-NET-40. It describes what is actually happening when you install .net 4.5
You may ask the vendor of the program to recompile it using the latest version of DevExpress controls.

Comment: That article is explanatory enough for me...in the end, I gave up and set up a virtual PC with .NET 4.0 only.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bug.

*Our controls fully support Visual Studio 2012 and .NET Framework 4.5 starting with version 12.1.6. We are also going to release version 11.2.13 with the runtime compatibility with .NET Framework 4.5 soon.*

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q430478

Is there any way you can attach a debugger to it and see what the exception is?

Answer (score 1):

There is two different flavours of .Net. It is possible that the version you use is a limited .Net (Client Profile) and the program you try to run requires the full version.
But according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx 4.5 is only available as full.